# Is there any way to login even without internet connection in AWS amplify react native expo project

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I want to make my application work even offline. I want below process to work in my application.

1. login with internet connection
2. logout with internet connection
3. disconnect internet connection
4. login without internet connection

how to achieve this functionality in my application. the technologies are react native expo and amplify cognito authentication.

I tried to use local storage service SQLite

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your mobile app to continue working, even without an internet connection.

You can use [Amplify's datastore](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js/) to address many of the complexities associated with online/offline scenarios.

If someone explicitly logs off / signs out of your application, correct code should remove the local session (cookie and/or other saved state) and require the next user to sign in.

You will not be able to authenticate a user with no internet connection. In theory, if the cellular network is available, you could initiate an SMS message to your backend, which could respond with a link (having temporary credentials) that would be opened by the app. However, if the app was in a "signed out" state, the credentials would not be helpful as cached data would/should have been removed.

If a user's session token is still valid, you could bypass your login screen. Within a native app, you could use biometric auth (e.g. face-id, touch-id) and/or a PIN to allow users to continue using the app while offline.